# Iterate two arrays to create a series of lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am hoping to multiply an array (Range) by each of the values in a second array (ISO). This would then output a series of arrays i.e: 
`ISO[0], ISO[1], ISO[2]...`

This is the code that I have but I can't get it to iterate properly, is there a shortcut that I am missing?

```
ISO = [0.0000005, 0.000001, 0.0000025, 0.000004, 0.000006,
                0.000009, 0.000013, 0.000021, 0.000033, 0.000052, 0.000084, 0.00013,
       0.00021, 0.00033, 0.00052, 0.00084, 0.00130, 0.0021, 0.0033]

d = len(ISO)

Range = np.arange(0, 300, 1)
for [i] in ISO:
       variance = []
       for [y] in Range:
              a = i * y
              variance[i].append(a)
              y = y+1
       i = i+1
```

Comment: Why are you adding those brackets around `[i]` & `[y]` ?

Comment: The following lines also appear to be unnecessary... `d = len(ISO)` `y= y+1` and `i = i+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to multiply an array `Range` by each element of an array `ISO` and get `n` arrays as a result (`n` being the length of array `ISO`).

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

ISO = np.array([0.0000005, 0.000001, 0.0000025, 0.000004, 0.000006,
            0.000009, 0.000013, 0.000021, 0.000033, 0.000052, 0.000084,
            0.00013,0.00021, 0.00033, 0.00052, 0.00084, 0.00130, 0.0021, 0.0033])

Range = np.arange(0, 300, 1)


result = np.multiply(ISO.reshape(len(ISO),1),Range)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something more like this...

```
import numpy as np

ISO = [0.0000005, 0.000001, 0.0000025, 0.000004, 0.000006,
                0.000009, 0.000013, 0.000021, 0.000033, 0.000052, 0.000084, 0.00013,
       0.00021, 0.00033, 0.00052, 0.00084, 0.00130, 0.0021, 0.0033]

variance = {}
Range = np.arange(0, 300, 1)
for i in ISO:
    results = []
    for y in Range:
        a = i * y
        results.append(a)
    variance[i] = results
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a more "numpy-esque" way of doing it:

```
np_ISO=np.array(ISO)
range = np.arange(0, 300)

variance_iso=np_ISO[:,None] * range
```